# One to One broken column mapping for id in jpa?

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I have three tables called `user`, `profile`, `branch` and one more table to link these three, `userprofilebranch` table.

My problem is

1. Branch table is a master table from where I fetch some details and assign a branch to the user, where branch id is a PK.
2. Same as branch I have a profile master table I do the same where profile id is PK.
3. I have a user table while saving the user I want to persist the `branchid`, `profileid`, and `userid` in `userprofilebranch` table.

**User.java**

```
 public class User implements Serializable, UserDetails {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @Column(name="USER_ID", nullable=false)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long userId ;

    @Column(name="USERNAME")
    private String userName ;

    @Column(name="FIRST_NAME")
    private String firstName ;

    @Column(name="LAST_NAME")
    private String lastName ;



    @OneToOne(optional=true, mappedBy="mappedUser")
    private UserProfileBranch mappedUserProfileBranch;
    public User() {
        super();
    }

    public void setUserId( Long userId ) {
        this.userId = userId ;
    }
    public Long getUserId() {
        return this.userId;
    }

    public void setFirstName( String firstName ) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }
    public String getFirstName() {
        return this.firstName;
    }

    public void setLastName( String lastName ) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }
    public String getLastName() {
        return this.lastName;
    }
}
```

**UserProfileBranch.java**

```
 public class UserProfileBranch {

 @EmbeddedId @AttributeOverrides({
        @AttributeOverride(name="userId", column=@Column(name="USER_ID")),
        @AttributeOverride(name="branchCode", column=@Column(name="BRANCH_CODE")),
        @AttributeOverride(name="profileId", column=@Column(name="PROFILE_ID"))
    })
    private UserProfileBranchComposite userProfileBranchCompositeKey;   

    @OneToOne(optional=true,fetch= FetchType.LAZY) @PrimaryKeyJoinColumns({
        @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="USER_ID", referencedColumnName="USER_ID"), 
        @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="BRANCH_CODE", referencedColumnName="BRANCH_CODE"),
        @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="PROFILE_ID", referencedColumnName="PROFILE_ID")
    })
    private User mappedUser;    

   public UserProfileBranchComposite getUserProfileBranchCompositeKey() {
    return userProfileBranchCompositeKey;
  }

   public void setUserProfileBranchCompositeKey(
        UserProfileBranchComposite userProfileBranchCompositeKey) {
    this.userProfileBranchCompositeKey = userProfileBranchCompositeKey;
}
}
```

**UserProfileBranchCompositeKey**

```
@Embeddable
public class UserProfileBranchComposite implements Serializable{    

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Column(name="USER_ID",nullable= false)
private Long userId;
    
@Column(name="BRANCH_CODE",nullable= false)
private String branchCode;

@Column(name="PROFILE_ID")
private String profileId;

public UserProfileBranchComposite() {
    
}
public UserProfileBranchComposite(Long userId) {
    this.userId = userId;
}

public Long getUserId() {
    return userId;
}

public void setUserId(Long userId) {
    this.userId = userId;
}


public String getBranchCode() {
    return branchCode;
}

public void setBranchCode(String branchCode) {
    this.branchCode = branchCode;
}

public String getProfileId() {
    return profileId;
}

public void setProfileId(String profileId) {
    this.profileId = profileId;
}
}
```

when I execute the code I got this error

```
 Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: broken column mapping for: mappedUser.id of: in.vit.leasing.security.domain.model.UserProfileBranch
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractPropertyMapping.initPropertyPaths(AbstractPropertyMapping.java:178)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractPropertyMapping.initIdentifierPropertyPaths(AbstractPropertyMapping.java:242)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractPropertyMapping.initPropertyPaths(AbstractPropertyMapping.java:222)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.initOrdinaryPropertyPaths(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2457)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.initPropertyPaths(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2494)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.postConstruct(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3949)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.SingleTableEntityPersister.<init>(SingleTableEntityPersister.java:453)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
    at org.hibernate.persister.internal.PersisterFactoryImpl.create(PersisterFactoryImpl.java:163)
    at org.hibernate.persister.internal.PersisterFactoryImpl.createEntityPersister(PersisterFactoryImpl.java:135)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:401)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1859)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:857)
```

I am not getting where I mapped wrong. can some one help me to fix this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My advice from personal experience: don't use composite keys with Hibernate, use generated primary keys. Benefits:

1. simpler mapping, less headaches
2. less storage (one column for storing foreign keys, not three)
3. better performance

If you want it the hard way: try to change the owner to User.java:

```
@OneToOne(optional=true)
@JoinColumns({
    @JoinColumn(name="KEY_USER_ID", referencedColumnName="USER_ID", updateable=false, insertable=false),
    @JoinColumn(name="KEY_BRANCH_CODE", referencedColumnName="BRANCH_CODE", updateable=false, insertable=false),
    @JoinColumn(name="KEY_PROFILE_ID", referencedColumnName="PROFILE_ID", updateable=false, insertable=false)
})
private UserProfileBranch mappedUserProfileBranch;
```

Comment: Thankyou , It helped me alot

Comment: Anytime! Did you change the owner or did you replace the composite keys with generated ones?

Comment: i have replaced with composite keys and added those fields in table :-) and i have one more query. if i does the same for many to many case where the changes will take place in above joincolumns query